# How to enable Cloudwatch Logs for API Gateway using Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Hi I'm trying to enable Cloudwatch logs in API Gateway using Cloudformation. However, I do not find the the documentation to do so. All I can find is `Logginglevel` in the official documentation which doesn't seem to be the solution.

For context I'm looking to achieve this using Cloudformation but don't know how to. Please help.

[image: Done Manually here from console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These log settings are set using [MethodSetting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-stage-methodsetting.html):

- `DataTraceEnabled` - is for "Log full requests..."
- `LoggingLevel` is for "Log level"
- `MetricsEnabled` is for "Enable detailed CloudWatch metrics"

Comment: I tried this and get this error `StageDescription cannot be specified when stage referenced by StageName already exists` Any Idea why?

Comment: @RedBottle Can you update your question with relevant template parts?

Comment: Nvm this is a seperate issue. My initial question is answered. Thank you.

Comment: This is for v1. Is there anything for ApiGatewayV2? I've created a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/67670073/2948212

Answer (score 0):

`Yaml` template snippet for ApiGateway V1:

```
SomeApiStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      RestApiId:
        Ref: SomeApi
      DeploymentId:
        Ref: SomeApiDeployment
      StageName: some-api
      Description: Some Api stage
      MethodSettings:
        - ResourcePath: "/*"
          HttpMethod: "*"
          MetricsEnabled: true
          DataTraceEnabled: true
          LoggingLevel: "INFO"
```