# Enable CloudWatch logs in API GatewayV2 Stage with cloud formation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347621/how-to-enable-cloudwatch-logs-for-api-gateway-using-cloudformation) but it does not use `AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage`, and I need the `AutoDeploy` that only the V2 seems to provide.

How do I enable CloudWatch logs and log full message data (as per the image) using CloudFormation in an AWS API Gateway?

[image: Enable cloudwatch logs in AWS Console]

I can't find anything at the documentation for the Stage
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-stage.html#cfn-apigatewayv2-stage-deploymentid

I am using an autodeployed stage. I am able to create the log groups, the IAM role to write logs in CloudWatch, but I can't enable the logging itself.

```
wsApiGateway:
  Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
  Properties:
    Name: foo-ws-gateway
    Description: Api Gateway for Websockets
    ProtocolType: WEBSOCKET
    RouteSelectionExpression: $request.body.action
    DisableExecuteApiEndpoint: true # I use custom domain

# routes and integrations ommitted.

wsApiStage:
  Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage
  DependsOn:
    - wsConnectRoute
    - wsSendRoute
    - wsDisconnectRoute
  Properties:
    StageName: production
    Description: Autodeploy in production
    AutoDeploy: true
    ApiId: !Ref wsApiGateway
    AccessLogSettings:
      DestinationArn: !GetAtt wsApiGatewayLogGroup.Arn
      Format: '{"requestTime":"$context.requestTime","requestId":"$context.requestId","httpMethod":"$context.httpMethod","path":"$context.path","routeKey":"$context.routeKey","status":$context.status,"responseLatency":$context.responseLatency, "responseLength":$context.responseLength, "integrationError":$context.integration.error}'
```

I also had to go to ApiGateway previous version to define the Account so that I could specify the IAM role ARN that has write access to CloudWatch logs in the account (The section on Settings at,the console's API Gateway). It doesn't seem to have a `AWS::ApiGateway2::Account`.

```
apiGatewayAccountConfig:
  Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Account"
  Properties:
    CloudWatchRoleArn: !GetAtt apiGatewayWatchLogsRole.Arn
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> How do I enable CloudWatch logs and log full message data (as per the image) using CloudFormation in an AWS API Gateway?

You can't. **Execution logs are not supported** by HTTP API (i.e. ApiGatewayV2) as explained by AWS [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/):

> **HTTP APIs currently support access logging only**, and logging setup is different for these APIs. For more information, see Configuring logging for an HTTP API.

Comment: Notice the original question clearly shows `AccessLogSettings` configured, so this _is_ an attempt to use access logs rather than execution logs.